# Ошибка при считывании данных из csv

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, dataframe, csv

Пытаюсь считать данные из `csv`.

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "A:/Pycharm projects/machine learning/main.py", line 10, in <module>
        df.columns = ['X', 'Y']
    File "A:\Pycharm projects\machine learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5080, in __setattr__
        return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
    File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 69, in 
        pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
    File "A:\Pycharm projects\machine learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 638, in _set_axis
        self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    File "A:\Pycharm projects\machine learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 155, in set_axis
        'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
    ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

***Код:***

```py
import pandas
import matplotlib
import numpy
import seaborn

from sklearn import linear_model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pandas.read_csv('linear_regression_df.csv')
    df.columns = ['X', 'Y'] # error
    df.head()
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает из-за того, что в DataFrame `df` всего один столбец, а вы пытаетесь присвоить названия двум столбцам.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [3]: df.columns = ['X', 'Y']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b061930ee075> in <module>
----> 1 df.columns = ['X', 'Y']
...
skipped
...    
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Не видя ваших данных, трудно сказать в чем проблема, но скорее всего в файле `linear_regression_df.csv` использован разделитель полей отличный от `,` или там на самом деле только один столбец.